how to embeed react app in iframe in salesforce webchat
how to embeed react app in iframe in salesforce webchat
Not able for this getting: Refused to display 'https://yourdomain.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
but alredy added ngnix domain.
I am trying to embeed react based html in iframe to load webchat in salesforce webchat. but getting error while loadign the script tag.
but already that url in cors & trusted url section.
